# IF(ISBLANK(V4),"",TODAY()-V4) for the Day Past Due

Tags: excel

I trying to have a weekly schedule that keeps count of the Days Past Due and that stops when days count surpass 90,   Every time that the day count exceeds 7 in a given week, the number moves to one cell to the right and still the tally until 90 days (13 Weeks).

I have

```
IF(ISBLANK(V4),"",TODAY()-V4)
```

for the Day Past Due.

And for the Weekly Past Due it’s

```
=IF(ISBLANK(V4)-TODAY()<7,V4,""); =IF(ISBLANK(V4)-TODAY()<14,V4,"")…
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What's the `ISBLANK(v4)-TODAY()` doing? Do you always have a day in `V4`?

Comment: ISBLANK returns TRUE/FALSE or 1/0 respectively, not the value of V4.

Answer (score 1):

In the first cell I put min in W4:

```
=IF(V4<>"",MIN(TODAY()-$V4,7),"")
```

Then in X4 I put:

```
=IF(W4=7,MIN((TODAY()-$V4)-SUM($W4:W4),IF(COLUMN(B:B) = 13,6,7)),"")
```

And copied over 12 columns

[image]

Comment: Could you show me (in steps) how to copy excel in my questions?  Like the example that you have after the words "And copied over 12 columns".    I have tried numerous times...   but I just can't get down the process...    Thank you...

Comment: Put the formula in the cell.  Hit enter.  Then click on the cell again.  Hit Ctrl-C.  Then highlight the next 11 cells and hit Ctrl-V.

Comment: Days Past Due Weeks Past Due             
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 > 90 Days
31         31

Comment: Days Past Due Weeks Past Due             
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 > 90 Days
31         31

Comment: I am doing something wrong...  I'm highlighting the cells I want to copy on my excel sheet; hitting Ctrl-C. and then going to the "Add Comment"; hitting Ctrl-V.  But final product comes out Non Formatted.

Comment: It is sounding like you have a new question.  Please create a new post, but this sounds like that question would be better suited on: https://superuser.com